# create id for distinct duplicates using SAS

Tags: sas

I'm working on a data quality problem, and specifically detecting duplicates with fuzzy logic using COMPGED and COMPLEV functions.

I have detected duplicates, but per couple.
example: 
assuming that customers with customer_id equals 01, 02 and 03 reference to the same customer (let's call him John), my SAS program detects it this way:

duplicate_id  customer_id 
01-02 01 
01-02 02 
01-03 01
01-03 03
02-03 02
02-03 03

where duplicate_id is an id that I've created combining both customer ids to reference a couple of duplicates.

So what I want now is to have a unique id for John !

The final result that I want is :
duplicate_id  customer_id unique_id 
01-02 01 01
01-02 02 01
01-03 01 01
01-03 03 01
02-03 02 01
02-03 03 01

(Unique_id is a **new** id, different from customer_id. This means that 01 is a new id and **NOT** the first appearance of customer_id.

I had the idea to use undirected graph (Operational Research algorithm) but I don't have the licence for it, and I'm not sure if I can affect a new id even if it works.

Any ideas ?
Thanks !

Comment: It is not particularly clear to me what you are trying to do here.  Could you add more detail and/or examples, ie. you've given us what you have now, but what do you want the final result to look like?

Comment: I think I see what you want (these 6 records would all be assigned a single unique ID, right?) .  I suggest you show more sample input data and the output data you would want.  Perhaps input data with 10-15 records, some that have duplicates, some that do not.

Comment: @Quentin this is exactly what I want !

Comment: @RobertPenridge : Quentin has well explained what I want. I updated the question and added what the final result look like.

Comment: I think the first example from this paper might help. http://analytics.ncsu.edu/sesug/2014/AD-08.pdf

Comment: thx @Quentin ! 
the example is a good first step to find the solution. The expected result is not what I want but it really helps. Thanks again !

Comment: No problem. You might consider posting this question over at SAS-L. I see more fuzzy matching questions there. https://listserv.uga.edu/cgi-bin/wa?A0=SAS-L

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `id` per `by` group.  This is done by sorting the data set and then referencing your [`by group`](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000761931.htm) in combination with the `first. processing` and the [`retain`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000214163.htm) statement.

For example,

```
proc sort data = <lib>.<data> ;
   by name <other ids, etc>;
run;
quit;


data <lib>.<data>;
   set <lib>.<data>;
   by name; /* by sort from above */

   format id 10.;

   if first.name then id = 0;
      retain id;
      id = id + 1;
run;
```

## EDIT

...and then use `uuidgen` function reference [here](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2012/10/19/creating-a-somewhat-unique-id-using-the-uuidgen-function/) to create an id.

Hope that this helps.

Comment: I don't think this is what he wants.  He doesn't have name='John' yet.  I think he is trying to find a way to determine that all 6 of these records are from the same customer (because 01=02 and 01=03 and 02=03)

Comment: @Quentin thanks for clarification.  Updated answer with reference to `uuidgen` function.

Comment: I'm just guessing, but I don't think this is it either.  I think what [s]he wants is a way to make the by-group variable.  I think for the 6 records he showed, they are all from one by-group, and [s]he wants to make that by-group ID to group them all together.  So it's a chaining exercise, where 01=02 and 01=03 therefore 01 02 and 03 should all be assigned to same by-group.  I think. : )

Comment: @Quentin You're prob right :).  I'll let them update and then go from there.  Thanks.

Comment: @siegerts: Quentin has understood the problem. It's a chain problem (or undirected graph problem).

In fact this is the final step of a program that I developed based on a paper named "Fuzzy Matching using the COMPGED Function".

The customer with id=02 may be called 'Jonh' (typing error) but he has the same e-mail adress and mobile number as the customers 01 and 03. This means that it's the same customer duplicated.

Hope it's clear and thanks for help :-)